# Nova Boot Does not work for anything

Tags: scheduler, openstack, command-line-interface, openstack-nova

I am trying to use the nova boot command but i keep getting the "to few arguments" error.

```
nova boot --image this --flavor is --key-name usless --availability-zone nova:ubuntu
```

I have been at this for a while can someone just please post what i am doing wrong and not post a link. I have followed a few and have been going in circuls this whole time. That and what is --key-name.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct the nova boot command that you put. Where is the name of the server?

Comment: isn't that the "--availability-zone nova:ubuntu"

Comment: you whould use [--availability-zone <availability-zone>], but you need to declare what is the name of the server. Take a look in the documentation (http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/novaclient_commands.html) in which you can see the format of the nova boot command.

Comment: Im getting confused with the terminology. In this availability zone a Host?

Comment: No, Availability Zone enables you to arrange OpenStack compute hosts into logical groups and provides a form of physical isolation and redundancy from other availability zones, such as by using a separate power supply or network equipment (http://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ops/content/scaling.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help i really do appreciate it. I have another question is a "server" the same as a host then? The reason i ask is that i want to be able to boot an instance on a specific host, and not have it boot an instance on a random one. I know that i will need to modify the nova scheduler but i dont see it taking in a host id as an argument anywhere.

Comment: mmm, not completely sure if you need to modify the nova scheduler. To select the host where instances are launched, use the "--availability_zone zone:host" parameter on the nova boot command. You can obtain the list of zone executing the "nova hypervisor-list" which provide the information about the hosts name that you have to use (available). BUT to specify which roles can launch an instance on a specified host, enable the "create:forced_host" option in the policy.json file. By default, this option is enabled for only the admin role.